# How to show content on one domian from another domain without changing URL through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Let say I have two domains, domainA and domainB. Whenever somebody hits domainA in browser the contents from domainB should load. Is this possible?

I have tried below rules, but it redirects to domainB.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domainB.com/$1 [P]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrites look ok. Make sure mod_proxy is installed on the server.

Also, your RewriteCond pattern wouldn't match www.domainA.com, so you might want to drop the carent.